# Native C API for NVidia PhysX 3.4

Tags: game-engine, game-physics, bulletphysics, physx

I am looking through the recently open-sourced NVidia PhysX 3.4 and all I find are C++ classes - is the a header version or wrapper API that is C only?

Answer (score 0):

May be you must create your C Header wrapper C++ classes yourself. I did something similar here by [this article](http://blog.eikke.com/index.php/ikke/2005/11/03/using_c_classes_in_c.html) and it work well.